# Data model content not displaying on new controller/view MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display the Title in Post. but it wont list in the new index that works with the Post controller.

This is the index;

```
    @using Shegzstuffweb.Models;
    @model IEnumerable<Post>
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    @foreach (Post post in Model)
    {
      @post.Title <br />
    }
```

The Postcontroller is;

```
    public class PostController : Controller
{
    private BlogModel model = new BlogModel();



    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Post> posts =
            from post in model.Posts
            where post.DateTime < DateTime.Now
            orderby post.DateTime descending
            select post;
        ViewBag.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;


        return View(posts);
    }




    [ValidateInput(false)]

    public ActionResult Update(int? id, string title, string body, DateTime dateTime, string tags)
    {
        if (!IsAdmin)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

        Post post = GetPost(id);
        post.Title = title;
        post.Body = body;
        post.DateTime = dateTime;
        post.Tags.Clear();

        tags = tags ?? String.Empty;
        string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string tageName in tagNames)
        {
            post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tageName));

        }
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            model.Posts.Add(post);
        }
        model.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = post.ID });


    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        Post post = GetPost(id);
        StringBuilder tagList = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Tag tag in post.Tags)
        {
            tagList.AppendFormat("{0}", tag.Name);
        }
        ViewBag.Tags = tagList.ToString();
        return View(post);
    }

    private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
    {
        return model.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tagName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new Tag() { Name = tagName };
    }

    private Post GetPost(int? id)
    {
        return id.HasValue ? model.Posts.Where(x => x.ID == id).First() : new Post() { ID = -1 };
    }

    // TODO
    public bool IsAdmin { get { return true; /*Session["IsAdmin"] != null && (bool)Session["IsAdmin"]; */   } }
}
```

}

I only see the header and footer in the shared layout.

like this;

[the screenshot of when index runs on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq6DW.png)

I researched and was told that i must add a route. so i added it in App_start/ RouteConfig.cs

it became.

```
     public class RouteConfig
       {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
          {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Index",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

how do I get the data to display the title and subsequent modifications?

as you might have noticed, I am using two views. should I build the project on the Home controller?

Comment: Because `from post in model.Posts` returns no items - all you have done is initialize a new `BlogModel` which does not contain any `Posts` - its just an empty collection (and it has nothing to do with routes - you need to populate your model, or just call the database to get your items)

Comment: And code such as `model.Posts.Add(post);` in your `Update()` method makes no sense (the web is stateless - each time you make a request a new Controller is initialized - and as a result `model` is a **new** instance of `BlogModel`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, I think i populated it with the Edit view. I will edit the main post to be more understandable.

Comment: Read my 2nd comment - as soon as you redirect, the `model` instance is disposed and in the `Index()` method a new instance of `BlogModel` is created (and it does not contain any items)

Comment: please what do you suggest about model.Posts.Add(post);

Comment: You save your data to the database, and then in the `Index()` you get it from the database

Comment: alright. Thanks